# Installing chained dependency with pip and requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to use a requirements.txt file to install a couple of libraries using pip. My problem is that one library (`pyfasttext`) requires another (`Cython`) to be installed first. If I have both in the same requirements file, the installation of `pyfasttext` fails with `ImportError: No module named 'Cython'`.

Is it possible to specify this in one file or do I need to use two different requirements files and run those after another?

Comment: You can add cython to the beginning of the file.

Comment: @Mick_ Moving the packages up or down in the requirements file will have no effect at all.

Comment: @silent you will have to split the installation in two commands: `pip install cython && pip install -r requirements.txt`. If you are unable to install both packages in one pass (e.g. with `pip install cython pyfasttext` in a clean environment), then there is no trick to combine both reqs in one requirement file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that `pyfasttext` requires `Cython` but that its [`setup.py`](https://github.com/vrasneur/pyfasttext/blob/7dd28b6b7faa85136e8d64e469cb7ccb6663aae9/setup.py#L3) imports `Cython` before installing it. You have to install `Cython` first yourself.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Both the other answer and the upvoted comment are wrong or ill-adviced.

Comment: that's what a figured. Thanks for confirming anyway!